# PHP "cannot access protected property"

Tags: php, oop

This is my first OOP program, so please don't be mad at me :)
The problem is that I've got the following error:

> Cannot access protected property Code::$text in  D:\xampp\htdocs\php\OOP\coder_class.php on line 47

The program simply codes a string and decodes it. I'm not sure if this is a good example to learn OOP.

```
<?php
class Code
{
    // eingabestring
    protected $text;

            public function setText($string)
            {
                $this->text = $string;
            }

            public function getText()
            {
                echo $this->text;
            }
}

class Coder extends Code
{
    //Map for the coder
    private $map = array(
        '/a/' => '1',
        '/e/' => '2',
        '/i/' => '3',
        '/o/' => '4',
        '/u/' => '5');

            // codes the uncoded string
    public function coder() 
    {
        return preg_replace(array_keys($this->map), $this->map, parent::text);      
    }
}

class Decoder extends Code
{
    //Map for the decoder
    private $map = array(
    '/1/' => 'a',
    '/2/' => 'e',
    '/3/' => 'i',
    '/4/' => 'o',
    '/5/' => 'u');

            // decodes the coded string
            public function decoder()
    {
        return preg_replace(array_keys($this->map), $this->map, parent::text);      
    }
}

$text = new code();
    $text -> setText("ImaText");
    $text -> coder();
    $text -> getText();
```

?>

Can some help me fixing this . Am new to PHP .

Comment: The message is quite self-explanatory. Which one is line 47?

Comment: you need to add a method to get the text as only the class itself can process it. ie `public function getText() { return $this->text; }` then `echo $text->getText();`

Comment: ouh shit xD ! .. this is the wrong $map at the decoder !!

Comment: the right $map for the coder is private $map = array(
   '/a/' => '1',
   '/e/' => '2',
   '/i/' => '3',
   '/o/' => '4',
   '/u/' => '5');

Comment: How do you intend for `echo $text->text;` to work? The `text` property is marked _protected_, which disables exactly this.

Comment: As Alvaro has demonstrated, you only need six lines to demonstrate this problem. Please produce a debugging [testcase](http://sscce.org) in future; you should already have done this as part of _your own debugging_ before resorting to asking for help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What's his question? What are protected properties? How should they be used? Best practices for accessing protected properties? It goes on and on. A syntax error and block of code with "Help" isn't a question.

Comment: @MikeB: I largely agree with that. I do not agree that it is a duplicate of the question you linked to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough. I have a tendency to pick the first one out of a list [when it's such a bad duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Cannot+access+protected+property+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: @MikeB: I feel your pain.

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Instead of `parent::text` you should use `$this->text`. Child classes can have access to protected properties of parent class.

Answer (score 3):

With:

```
protected $text;
```

And:

```
echo $text->text;
```

Is why you get the error. `protected` means that only descendants of the `Code` class can access that property, ie. `Coder` and `Decoder`. If you want to access it via `$text->text` it must be `public`. Alternatively, just write a `getText()` method; you've already written the setter.

Side note: the `public`, `private`, and `protected` keywords have virtually *nothing* to do with security. They are generally intended to enforce data/code/object integrity.

Answer (score 2):

Relevant code:

```
class Code
{
    protected $text;
}
$text = new code();
echo $text->text;
```

The property is not public, thus the error. It works as advertised.

Comment: The "getText" method is now working